# Insert new row below the selected cell or row

Tags: excel, vba

I have protected excel sheet. The first row is at no.10 and all new rows are inserted below.

I have put below code with command button to insert a new row at the bottom with same format and formula copied from above row. This works perfectly fine.

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect""
ActiveSheet.Range("A10").CurrentRegion.Offset(ActiveSheet.Range("A10").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1).Resize(2).EntireRow.FillDown
ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowDeletingRows:=True, AllowSorting:=True _
, AllowFiltering:=True
ActiveSheet.Protect "", True, True
```

But I cannot insert a new row in the middle of rows(with same format and formulas copied from above row).

Can someone please edit my code so that I can insert a new row anywhere in the middle of rows wherever I want to insert by highlighting with mouse click.

Of course the new row should be created below the highlighted cell and copied with same format and formulas as above row.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28943827/4539709

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Excel - Insert row below with same format including borders and frames](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28943492/vba-excel-insert-row-below-with-same-format-including-borders-and-frames)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub AddRow()  
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect "1234" 
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert 
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Cells.Locked = False 
    ActiveSheet.Protect "1234" 
End Sub
```